# When I turn on my light switch, there is a delay before the light comes on

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture

We have a ceiling fan light.  One swith controls the fan, the other the light.  When I turn on the light switch, there is a noticable delay (like a full second) before the light comes on.  Is it a wiring issue?  I notice no blinking, no other problems, just the delay.

Comment: is it a [low energy bulb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_fluorescent_lamp) (or normal fluorescent light)? some have a delay on start up

Comment: No, regular small fan light bulbs (incandescent)

Comment: Is it possibly not a standard hardwired switch? Some fans are controlled by radio remotes, and the receiving electronics could have a delay. If the switches are identical to your other typical light switches, this probably isn't it.

Comment: Another question.  Are the switches regular switches or is it something designed for ceiling fans?

Comment: Sounds like you have lazy electrons.  Or possibly a bad switch.

Comment: The switch is a standard hardwired switch, not a radio remote.

Comment: Of course, the lazy electrons is possible...it is in a teenager's room after all....

Comment: Have you opened up the fixture to see if there are any oddball electronics in there? I'm thinking support for a remote that you don't have. Mine has a remote and it's wired into a wall switch. The electronics for the remote cause the lamp to ramp up to full brightness about 1 second after you hit the wall switch.

Comment: Is it a dimmer switch or a switch with a dimmer control on the side?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those problems that you just have to work out systematically, don't be swayed by logic.

- If there is only one bulb change it.
- Check the wiring at the light and switch - see that the connections are tight.
- Change the switch.
- Try wiring a test lamp to the fixture.
- Call an electrician. You may have serious wiring issues.

Answer (score 2):

Also don't rule out the fan.  I've installed one fan that had a rather large capacitor on the light circuit.  Not sure of the reason of the capacitor but that light had a small delay when turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with an dimmer switch designed for use with LED and CF bulbs.  I was using incandescent bulbs.  I returned the dimmer switch to home depot and got a regular "for incandescent only" dimmer switch and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a combination switch with a Hunter fan.  My delay for the light to come on was several minutes and then sometimes the light would flash like a strobe light.  After reading comments from this site I decided to purchase another Hunter fan and see what happens.  I connected the fan and light.  It now comes on instantly without any delay.  I have another fan/light combo in another room.  The delay is only a couple of seconds but no other problem. My suggestion is to purchase a new light/fan if you are having the same problems that I was.  Not sure if it is safe to keep using it like mine was operating.
Apparently there was some regulation about delays that I have read in some other sites.

Answer (score -2):

It could be a defective light bulb. It is very odd.